# Create instanced triangles in react-three/fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I can create a triangle with BufferGeometry where `array=new Float32Array([0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0]);`

```
<mesh>
      <bufferGeometry attach="geometry">
        <bufferAttribute
          attachObject={["attributes", "position"]}
          count={3}
          array={array}
          itemSize={3}
        />
      </bufferGeometry>
      <meshBasicMaterial
        attach="material"
        color="#5243aa"
        wireframe={false}
        side={THREE.DoubleSide}
      />
    </mesh>
```

Now I want to create 1 triangle using `InstancedMesh`. However it doesn't work as expeced.

```
<instancedMesh ref={meshRef} args={[null as any, null as any, 1]}>
        <bufferGeometry attach="geometry">
          <bufferAttribute
            attachObject={["attributes", "position"]}
            count={3}
            array={position}
            itemSize={3}
          />
        </bufferGeometry>
        <meshBasicMaterial
          attach="material"
          color="#5243aa"
          wireframe={false}
          side={THREE.DoubleSide}
        />
      </instancedMesh>
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

Declare an instanced mesh where `vertices=[x1,y1,z1,...]` is the coordinates of the triangle:

```
<instancedMesh ref={meshRef} args={[null as any, null as any, 10]}>
        <bufferGeometry attach="geometry">
          <bufferAttribute
            attachObject={["attributes", "position"]}
            args={[vertices, 3]}
          />
        </bufferGeometry>
        <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
      </instancedMesh>
```

Update each instance's position and color:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (meshRef === null) return;
    if (meshRef.current === null) return;

    const mesh: any = meshRef.current;

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      //position
      tempObject.position.set(
        100 * Math.random(),
        100 * Math.random(),
        100 * Math.random()
      );
      tempObject.updateMatrix();
      mesh.setMatrixAt(i, tempObject.matrix);

      // color
      mesh.setColorAt(
        i,
        tempColor.setRGB(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())
      );
    }
  });
```

The result:

[image]